# How to resolve android.view.InflateException ? Works fine on Lollipop but not on other versions

Tags: android, android-compatibility

I made my First App and during the process I tested the app only on a lollipop API23 device.
Now I'm trying to run the same app on jellybean but it crashes there with

```
09-28 16:46:44.507    9517-9517/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at com.zap.Kalanjali.FirstHome$MyAdapter.getView(FirstHome.java:88)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2177)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1840)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:675)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:736)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1655)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2012)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.onLayout(ScrollView.java:1459)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1043)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1976)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1730)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMes
```

and Line 88 in FirstHome Fragment is :

```
itemView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.card_list_item, parent, false);
```

How do I solve this? What are the things I need to keep in my mind to make the app compatible with all API levels?

Comment: You must ensure this "getActivity()" retrieve the context of app, maybe is this the reason of crash.

Comment: Looks like you are using card views without the support library. Please trim the stacktrace and and more code the card_list_item.xml for example.

Comment: https://github.com/zeetherocker/Kalanjali-2015    This is the entire code. Yes, @e4c5 I am using CardView. and I'm really not able to get around this error. Please take a look at the code when you have time

Comment: sorry don't have the time to look at the entire code and that's not what stackoverflow is about. Please post just the layout file as discussed thanks.

Comment: Thank you e4c5. I figured out the error.. I commented that line which was giving me errors. And later put another layout there. Finally figured out that its coz of the ripple effect file that I had used. Now it's fixed.. Thanks a lot anyways :)